# Regression with an unrepresentative sample

Tags: regression, sampling

We commonly fit regression models to estimate the conditional expectation function $\mathrm{E}(Y|X=x)$. We fit models by minimizing a loss function (e.g. sum of squared errors) on the training sample. An intuitive motivation for this is that we want a model which minimizes said loss function on the population, but since we only have access to the sample we minimize the loss on that instead. If a given sample $x_s,y_s$ is representative of the population (i.e. if $x_s,y_s \sim F_{X,Y}$, where $F_{X,Y}$ is the joint distribution of the population) then this approach makes sense and there's a lot of theory, e.g. maximum likelihood, to back it up.

My question is about the situation where we have an unrepresentative sample $x_u,y_u$, where $x_u$ has not been drawn from $F_X$. Unrepresentative samples can easily arise through non-random sampling techniques, such as those based on availability of data. Obviously, if the marginal population distribution $F_X$ is unknown then the best we can do is fit to the sample and hope for the best, but what about the situation where $F_X$ is known? Intuitively it would seem that some kind of importance sampling could be applied here. Is there a name for this situation, and is there a standard approach for dealing with it?

EDIT: I found that this problem is known as "covariate shift" in the machine learning community. Proposed solutions are based on the idea of importance sampling, but the more successful methods avoid explicit density estimation (e.g. [this paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2007/file/be83ab3ecd0db773eb2dc1b0a17836a1-Paper.pdf)).

Comment: Maybe this work will be helpful: [Statistical inference with non-probability survey samples](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/12-001-x/2022002/article/00002-eng.htm) (thanks to @StasK for recommending this article in another platform.)

Comment: A useful mantra is, "The data target the processes that produced the data."

Comment: @BigBendRegion What does that mean in this context?

Comment: Give more details of the specific context. What is your data-generating process, specifically? That is what the statistics are aiming at.

Comment: @BigBendRegion I'm building a model which predicts one meteorological variable using measurements of several others. The relationship between $x$ and $y$ may be assumed to hold identically everywhere, however the distribution of $x$ in my training sample is known to be different from the distribution of $x$ where the model will be deployed.

Comment: This is not much of a problem, since it is just X. The only issue is that if the sampled data are sparse at the X's where you actually want to make your predictions (due to the unrepresentative sample), then your predictions might be less accurate than desired, due to sampling variability. But from your description, assuming you are correct, there is no bias.